# getting started with socket.io without nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have started working on socket.io. As i'm new to socket.io so i don't know much about it. can anyone tell me whether node is must for socket.io or not ? can we use socket.io as standalone without node or express ?

Comment: Did you check their [wiki](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki)? Search for "In other languages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use socket.io as standalone. But you can use it in Languages other than nodeJS like [Eelco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451543/eelco) said.

socket.io can be used in: Erlang, Android, Java, Lua, Objective-C, C, C++, QT QML, Perl, Go, Python, Ruby, Rust, Flash, Haxe, PHP, .NET, C++/Win32 and unity3d.

Comment: thanks alot devian , if we want to use it with java , is their any special api/jar in java to support socket.io ?

Comment: Yes, here are some of them: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client, https://github.com/keesun/mod-socket-io, https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java, https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio

Comment: thanks alot @devian you are very helping , i need to use socket.io with play framework with java , by Google about it  i came to know that play framework works with netty server , do we need to use netty server must or there any other alternative to use socket.io with play ?