# Python Client connect to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there any way to connect with **python client** to a **nodejs server**(*socket.io*)?

I have web real time chat, but I want to connect to the chat to the same server and the same room from an stand-alone app for PC. It doesn't need to be especially python, but I was thinking it can run on every OS and it is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is now supported not only on node.js now. Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859637/2866570):

> socket.io can be used in: Erlang, Android, Java, Lua, Objective-C, C, C++, QT QML, Perl, Go, Python, Ruby, Flash, Haxe, PHP, .NET, C++/Win32and unity3d.

Just google for `socket.io <your programming language>`

Comment: Jees, thanks a lot, I never thought it would be so easy.